# Finding the Jordan Form of a transformation defined by $T(X)=AX$ when $A,X \in M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb C)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

> Given $A=\left(\matrix{0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1}\right)$ and define $T(X)=AX$. when $A,X \in M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb C)$
>
> Find the Jordan Form of T

I found that the minimal polynomial is $(t-1)(t+1)$ therefore $T$ is diagonalizable. However, I'm not sure how to find the amount of each eigenvalue to put in the diagonal without explicity finding the $16\times16$ representative matrix of T.

Comment: X is also a 4×4 matrix or 4×1?

Comment: By the $16\times 16$ comment, I guess it should be a $4\times 4$ matrix. It is also in the title. But you are right, the reader should not guess, and it should have been repeated.

Comment: Edited to repeat it in the body

Comment: This might help: $(T-I)X=0\Longleftrightarrow (A-I)X=0$

Comment: @Lozenges I thought about that but it seemed it might lead to a lot of equations. Might be worth exploring though, I could be wrong.

Comment: a nonzero column of $X$ is an eigenvector of $A$

Comment: @Lozenges Not sure what you meant by the non zero eigenvector comment. But I wend ahead and solved the equation $(A-I)X=0$ and it wasn't that bad actually. it let me to a solution of dimension $8$ which is all I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I identify a $4\times 4$ matrix by a vector of length $16$ by reading it from top to bottom, from left to right. So the first four coordinates are from the first column, etc.

Then $T$ is diagonal in the last $8$ coordinates: identical on coordinates $9-12$, and negative of the identity on $13-16$, so that part is covered.

Furthermore, $T$ switches the first four coordinates by the second four as a product of four transpositions. You can view these transpositions separately. The matrix of a transposition of two coordinates is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, whose Jordan normal form is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

So the Jordan normal form of $T$ is diagonal with eigenvalues:

$$1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1$$

Comment: Nice thinking about the transformation gets you most of the way and the transposition trick is nice. Thanks